# Delete a single file from AWS s3 bucket?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete a single file from AWS s3 bucket and my code is as below:

```
$removeUploadedDocFromTestingFolder = array(
          "removeFromTestFolder" =>
            array(
                "bucket" => "my-bucket"
            ),
             "AccessKeys" =>
            array(
                "access_key" => "my access key",
                "seceret_key" => "my secret key"
            )

    ); 
$_SERVER['HOME'] = DIR_HOME;
ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Credentials\Credentials;

$client = S3Client::factory();

//$objError = new ErrorReporting();

$bucket = $removeUploadedDocFromTestingFolder['removeFromTestFolder']['bucket'];

//testing file setup on local server....
$file1 = "my-file"; 

//File reference on cloud.....Object URL
$file1_cloud = "https://Object URL/myFile/myFile";

echo "here 0";      
$client->deleteObject($bucket, $file1_cloud);
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong that the code is not deleting the file.

I tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
try {
//$client->deleteObject($bucket, $file1_cloud);
$result = $client->deleteObject(['Bucket' => 'my-bucket','Key' => 'myFile.png']);
} catch(\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
echo "error"+$e;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The object is not being deleted because you have asked S3 to delete a non-existent object, and S3 treats this as a no-op rather than an error. This is because you have indicated a URL rather than the key of the object.

An example of an S3 object key is:

```
testing/cats/fluffykins.png
```

Note that it's not a URL and it doesn't begin with forward slash.

An example of the correct way to call the PHP [deleteObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#deleteobject) function is:

```
$result = $s3Client->deleteObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $key,
]);
```

Note that it takes an array of parameters, including bucket and key. It assumes PHP 5.4 or later in which you can use the short array syntax, which replaces `array()` with `[]`.

Comment: okay so in my case its /TestFile/2005+Mazda+Axela+%23459.docx am i right?

Comment: not working start getting error: Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Guzzle\Service\Client::getCommand() must be an array, string given, called in vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 76 and defined in vendor/guzzle/guzzle/src/Guzzle/Service/Client.php on line 79

Comment: Remove the forward slash as that is not part of the key. Also, try this out with a simple key first like test101/cat.png. If that works and yours doesn't then you'll know that its because you are incorrectly supplying the plus/space and/or character encoding (e.g. # to %23). Then you can investigate those in more detail, until you get it working.

Comment: Following is also not working:  $file1_cloud = "TestFile/463e4c61fc342cb71c04c4d6b302f8bb.png";   $result = $client->deleteObject([
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $file1_cloud,
]);

Comment: There is a really useful tool called the awscli. You should install it and test. If it works with awscli but fails with your code, then your code is wrong. If it fails with awscli then *you* are doing something wrong (for example mis-typing the object key or using credentials for the wrong AWS account).

Answer (score -1):

I've resolved the issue by using the following code:

```
    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
      'key' => "mykey",
      'secret'  => "my secret key"
   ));
//File reference on cloud.....
$file1_cloud = "TestFile/myFile.png";

$result = $client->deleteObject(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => 'TestFile/myFile.png'));
```

Comment: It's generally not OK to take the key part of someone else's answer, then write it up as your own answer. StackOverflow doesn't work well when you do this.

Comment: To be fair, it is fine to take someone's answer, improve on it, and then post your own work. But, give the other answer the tick/check mark if you can - you don't get points for a self-accept anyway.